# Python + Selenium, GeckoDriver opens Firefox browser then does nothing

Tags: python, selenium, firefox, geckodriver, selenium-firefoxdriver

I'm new to python and selenium really enjoying learning a bit.

Just dipping my toes into selenium and having some trouble getting this script to work.

it's not given an error it just opens browser and does nothing.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

kw = input("enter the keyword to search on google")

# creates firefox session
driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=r'C:\Users\Web\Desktop\geckodriver-v0.18.0-win32\geckodriver.exe')
driver.implicitly_wait(30)


# navigate to google
driver.get("http://www.google.com")

#get the search textfield
search_field = driver.find_element_by_id("lst-ib")
search_field.clear()

#enter search kw and submit
search_field.send_keys(kw)
search_field.submit()

lists = driver.find_element_by_class_name("_Rm")

print ("Found " + str(len(lists)) + "searches:")

i=0
for listitem in lists:
    print(listitem)
    i=i+1
    if(i>10):
        break

driver.quit()
```

Comment: update gecko driver and browser.

Answer (score 1):

While you work with `Selenium` 3.4.3, `geckodriver` v0.17.0, `Mozilla Firefox` 53.0 through Python 3.6.1; as you have been trying to create a list out of `driver.find_element_by_class_name("_Rm")` and print the list items, I assume instead of the `WebElements` you want to print the links with-in those e.g. `https://pypi.python.org/pypi/selenium` etc. Here is your own code block with some simple tweaks which you can use to achieve the following:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.firefox_binary import FirefoxBinary

binary = FirefoxBinary('C:\\Program Files\\Mozilla Firefox\\firefox.exe')
kw = input("Provide the keyword to search through google : ")

# creates firefox session
driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_binary=binary, executable_path="C:\\Utility\\BrowserDrivers\\geckodriver.exe")
driver.implicitly_wait(30)


# navigate to google
driver.get("http://www.google.com")

#get the search textfield
search_field = driver.find_element_by_id("lst-ib")
search_field.clear()

#enter search kw and submit
search_field.send_keys(kw)
search_field.submit()

lists = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("_Rm")
print ("Elements found : {}".format(len(lists)))

i=0
print("Here are the links : ")
for listitem in lists:
    print(listitem.get_attribute("innerHTML"))
    i=i+1
    if(i>10):
    break

driver.quit()
```

The output on the console is as follows:

```
Provide the keyword to search through google : Selenium
Elements found : 11
Here are the links : 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selenium_(software)
www.seleniumhq.org/
www.guru99.com/selenium-tutorial.html
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selenium_(software)
toolsqa.com/selenium-tutorial/
selenium-python.readthedocs.io/
selenium-python.readthedocs.io/getting-started.html
https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium
https://github.com/SeleniumHQ
https://www.pluralsight.com/courses/selenium
www.scalatest.org/user_guide/using_selenium
```